# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Screen not waking up from "blank" while using nvidia-driver-510

Tags: drivers, nvidia

When the screen fades to black ("Screen Blank" mode in Power options) like 95% of the time it won't wake back up upon mouse or keyboard input. This only started happening after I installed **nvidia-driver-510** and started using it. I tried switching to **xserver-xorg-video-nouveau** and it starts working fine again. How would I go about troubleshooting and fixing this issue? Is there a big difference in the performance of those drivers in the first place or should I just use the open-source driver?

For more detail:

- Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad P53
- CPU: Intel Core i5-9400H
- GPU: Quadro T1000
- BIOS: Lenovo N2NET49W
- BIOS rev: 1.34
- Firmware rev: 1.14
- Ubuntu: 22.04 LTS
- GNOME version: 42.1

After ManOnTheMoon's comment, I tried disabling Wayland and it does indeed fix the blank screen issue, but it also makes me lose 3-finger touchpad workspace control which is something I use quite a lot and cant really live without.

Comment: for login to work as "intended", you can use nvidia-driver-510 with x11 or nouveau with wayland. I've tried both and don't really "feel" much difference using either (with older 940mx).  However, if you are using CUDA, you'll need nvidia driver. Lastly, if you end up using nvidia driver,  it's more stable to run nvidia driver with x11 for now. Nvidia driver with wayland is still very glitchy from my usage since moving to 22.04

Answer (score 1):

it happens on my ubuntu 22.04 installation with nvidia-griver-510. I have to press ctrl + f3 and ctrl + f2 to recover UI.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1244797)